# How Do I Create a User Profile Update View/Form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I trying to update the user profile but I can't get that what mistake I do here.

```
#forms.py
class AddStudentUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "first_name", "last_name"]

class AddStudentStaffForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = ["gender", "dob", "mob", "img"]

#views.py
def editProfile(request, user, id):
    if request.POST:
        staffform = AddStudentStaffForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=request.user.staff_profile)
        userform = AddStudentUserForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if staffform.is_valid():
            staffform.save()

        if userform.is_valid():
            userform.save()
            return redirect(profile,user)
    return render(request, 'edit.html')

#models.py
class Staff(models.Model):
    Male = 'Male'
    Female = 'Female'
    Other = 'Other'
    GENDER_CHOICE = (
        (Male, 'Male'),
        (Female, 'Female'),
        (Other, 'Other')
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='staff_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICE, default=Male)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    mob = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='staff/', blank="True", null="True")
    objects = models.Manager()

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Staff.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.staff_profile.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gender
```

I started to create a Student Management System project. But I faced some difficulties to develop it. I trying lot of to solve these problem but since I can't solve that.

Here if I want to update the Staff model fields like gender, dob, mob it will updated successfully but when I trying to update the User model fields like username, first_name, last_name it will not update. I think the `if userform.is_valid():` condition couldn't run, but I can't get what mistake I do here.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug why the form is not valid, try code below :

```
if userform.is_valid():
    userform.save()
    return redirect(profile,user)
else:
    print userform.errors #To see the form errors in the console.
```

Comment: Thanks, I try these and it will print ` <ul class="errorlist"><li>first_name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>last_name<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul> ` . Is there a mistake in my code?

Comment: the error is in html form, can you show your form here

Comment: you must pass first_name and last_name in the post request

Comment: In the form tag, I put those first_name and last_name input  tags and the method="POST" of the form tag in html.

Comment: print request.POST and find that if the form have first and last_name or not, if yes than check saving userform first and staffform later